# Optimalisation of lambda query

Tags: c#, lambda, query-optimization

this is my expression:

```
var d = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-60);
return db.Orders
.Where(o => o.CreateDate > d && o.Status > 3)
.Join(db.OrderItems, o => o.OrderId, o => o.OrderId, (o, p) => new { Order = o, OrderItem = p })
.Join(db.Customers, o => o.Order.CustomerId, o => o.CustomerId, (o, p) => new { o.Order, o.OrderItem, Customer = p })
.GroupBy(p => new {p.Customer.CustomerId, p.Customer.Name})
.Select(o => new CustomerMonthSale
{
CustomerId = o.Key.CustomerId,
Name = o.Key.Name,
Price = o.Sum(p => p.OrderItem.Price * p.OrderItem.Quantity)
})
.OrderByDescending(o => o.Price)
.Take(10).ToList();
```

it takes 6 seconds. It shoud give about 100 records but at the end of this query i get top 10. When counting orders and orderItems it is accessing maybe few thousand records. I doubt the problem is in size of database because i have similar expression accesing 6x larger amount of data and it takes 400ms. I think its something with select... but actually i have no idea.

Comment: How long does it take to execute? How many records are you accessing?

Comment: [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: it takes 6 seconds. It shoud give about 100 records but at the end of this query i get top 10. When counting orders and orderItems it is accessing maybe few thousand records. I doubt the problem is in size of database because i have similar expression accesing 6x larger amount of data and it takes 400ms. I think its something with select... but actually i have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. The query is correct. Problem was with "where" statement. It had checked column "createDate" which had no index set. I've set the index and whole page is ready after 500ms. Thanks everybody for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is at the end where it says: .ToList() 
I recommend you remove it, and I recommend using PLinq (Parallel Linq) instead, so your query would be like:

```
    var q = from order in db.Orders.AsParallel()
        where order.CreateDate > d && order.Status > 3
        join orderitems in db.OrderItems.AsParallel() on order.OrderId equals orderitems.OrderId
        join customers in db.Customers.AsParallel() on order.CustomerId equals customers.CustomerId
        orderby order.Price descending
        select new { Coloumn_name = value, Column_name = value };
    var FinalList = q.Take(10);
// Choose the column names you want, and assign the value you want i.e. order.CreateDate
// so the select will be: select new {Create_Date = order.CreateDate, Client_Id = order.CustomerId ...etc};
```